# Ethernet USB dongle works then randomly drops until restart

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet, usb-device

I've been using xubuntu 14.04 as my daily driver for a while now, as I've been getting into web development. I'm using a dell ultrabook that has no ethernet port (XPS 12 9Q33), and so I have usb 2.0 ethernet dongle.

The dongle will work fine for a couple hours and then randomly stop working. Unplugging and repluggin the dongle does not even register any lights on the dongle, it's like it's dead. If I restart the computer, things seem to work again.

When I type dmesg, the error code I get is

`asix 2-2:1.0 (unregistered net_device): Failed to enable hardware MII access`

After some searching around, I don't see any clear troubleshooting path...any ideas?